# Django dynamic urls connection

Tags: django, url, dynamic

I'm new in Django. I was got an error(***NoReverseMatch***) when implementing dynamic urls in Django.

I'm using Facebook API and hope to use the id of FB users to build the dynamic url of the profile page of my website.

Here is the error messages.

[error messages(***NoReverseMatch***)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFA70.jpg)

Here is the index.html.

```
<a id="user-all" href="" style="display:none;">
    <img src="" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
    <span id="header-usrname"></span>
</a>

<script>
    FB.api("/me", function(response) {
        $("#header-usrname").html(response.name);
        console.log(response.name + "/" + response.id)
        name = response.name;
        userID = response.id;
        $("#user-all").attr("href","https://mysite-yudbet.c9users.io/profile/" + userID);
    });
</script>
```

Here is the views.py.

```
def profile(request, usr_id):
    usr = Usr.objects.filter(usr_id=usr_id)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'usr_id': usr[0].usr_id})
```

Here is the urls.py.

```
urlpatterns = [url(r'^profile/(?P<usr_id>\d+)/$', views.profile, name='profile'),]
```

Comment: Your error message already says the parameter is empty, which means  in your javascript `userID` is empty, try to find out why.

Comment: No the problem is not in th userID, if you check the error message you will find that the userID is correctly set. The error refeeres to a reverse matching issue, but i don't see any reverse matching instructions in you code. Are you sure you shared the right part of you code. You did not use `reverse` somewhere in you code?

Comment: Thank you everyone, the problem had solved. It was caused by my syntax error at the href attr.